# Given $\Sigma a_n \to \alpha$ show that $\Sigma \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \to \beta$

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that if $\Sigma a_n$ is convergent, then $\Sigma {\sqrt {a_n} \over n}$ is also convergent.

I tried to use the comparison test but $\sqrt{a_n} >a_n $ so I couldn't go that rout.

Next I tried to prove that the second sequence is Cauchy given the first one is, as in

$$|\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i| \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow |\sum_{i=m}^{n} {\sqrt {a_i} \over i}| \lt \epsilon'$$

but I am not sure how I can get there ...

Comment: $p^2+q^2\ge {  2}pq$. Take $p=\sqrt {a_n}$ and $q=1/n$. Use the Comparison Test.

Comment: Of course, you need the $a_n$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMitra. This was the best answer among all I've seen.

Answer (score 8):

You can estimate partial sums using Cauchy-Shwartz.
Indeed,
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{a_k}}{k}\right)^2\le \sum_{k=1}^n{a_k}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the Cauchy-Shwartz theorem, or identity. I'm still a newby to this, so I will look into it and see if I can understand. Thanks though !

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality